# Foreach with Table - PHP and Leaguepedia API

Tags: php, arrays, api, datatables

I have this code to show how may times a champion was picked in a tournament for example ("Gragas : 2 Times" , "Syndra :4 times" , etc)

I'm using api from leaguepedia to recieve the informations

but im stucked right now, I'm having a problem when "echoing" my table to show the results.
So I want that  "qtd" be by the "pick" side (Image1) and if there's an easy way to show what I want.

```
// $Result is a CURL coming from leaguepedia api
$result = json_decode($file_contents);

// Double foreach to access the values from leaguepedia api
foreach ($result as $d) {
    foreach ($d as $data) {
        // $data->title->Team1Picks  is coming from league pedia api as a string separated by "," Ex:("Gragas,Shen,Maokai,etc")
        // So I need to explode to an array to count.
        $picks[] = explode(",", $data->title->Team1Picks);
    }
}

// $mostpicked is an array for me to count how many times a champion was picked
// $f is an array to see the names of the picked champions
foreach ($picks as $pick) {
    foreach ($pick as $total) {
        $mostPicked[] = $total;
        $f[] = $total;
    }
}

// Basically here I'm  counting how many times a champion was picked Ex : ("Gragas:2","Syndra:4" ,etc)     
asort($mostPicked);

$mostPicked = array_count_values($mostPicked);

$name = array_unique($f);

asort($name);

// Foreach to get all unique names from the picks Ex : ("Gragas","Shen",etc) instead of ("Gragas , "Gragas" , etc)
foreach ($name as $champ) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $champ . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

// This foreach to get the number of times a pick was made Ex : ("Gragas 2 Times")
foreach ($mostPicked as $pick) {    
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $pick . "</td>";   
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, this should do it.

```
// Hero name => pick count
$heroPicks = array();
foreach ($result as $d) {
    foreach ($d as $data) {
        //$data->title->Team1Picks  is coming from league pedia api as a string separated by "," Ex:("Gragas,Shen,Maokai,etc")
        // So i need to explode to an array to count.
        $picks = explode(",", $data->title->Team1Picks);
        foreach ($picks as $pick) {
            $pick = trim($pick);
            if (!array_key_exists($pick, $heroPicks)) {
                $heroPicks[$pick] = 0;
            }
            $heroPicks[$pick] += 1;
        }
    }
}

uasort($heroPicks, function($a, $b) {
    return $a - $b;
});
$heroPicks = array_reverse($heroPicks);

echo "Best picks:".PHP_EOL."<br />";
foreach ($heroPicks as $heroName => $pickCount) {
    echo $heroName." - ".$pickCount.PHP_EOL."<br />";
}
```

Comment: i adjusted to show in  my table and it worked very well , Thanks man !

Answer (score 1):

It seems because you're putting the `$pick` in a new `<tr>`

Try adjusting your loops so that you're building an array of `$champ=>$qtd` then you an iterate over that and build your table as desired.